# extract Album cover from .mp3 file with out using any external third party lib outside the angular

Tags: angular, typescript, base64

this is what i tried

```
extractMetadata(file: File, fileName) {

    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (event: any) => {
      const arrayBuffer = event.target.result;
      const dataView = new DataView(arrayBuffer);
      const header = String.fromCharCode(dataView.getUint8(0), dataView.getUint8(1), dataView.getUint8(2));
  
      if (header === 'ID3') {
        const version = dataView.getUint8(3);
        const majorVersion = dataView.getUint8(4);
        const minorVersion = dataView.getUint8(5);
        const flags = dataView.getUint8(6);
        const tagSize = this.calculateTagSize(dataView, 6);
  
        if (version === 3) {
          this.extractMetadataFromID3v2_3(dataView, tagSize);
        } else if (version === 4) {
          this.extractMetadataFromID3v2_4(dataView, tagSize);
        }
      }
    };
  
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  }

  calculateTagSize(dataView: DataView, offset: number): number {
    const byte1 = dataView.getUint8(offset + 6);
    const byte2 = dataView.getUint8(offset + 7);
    const byte3 = dataView.getUint8(offset + 8);
    const byte4 = dataView.getUint8(offset + 9);
  
    const size = (byte1 << 21) + (byte2 << 14) + (byte3 << 7) + byte4;
    return size + 10; // Add 10 bytes for the tag header
  }

  extractMetadataFromID3v2_3(dataView: DataView, tagSize: number) {
    let offset = 10; // Skip the tag header
    while (offset < tagSize) {
      const frameID = String.fromCharCode(dataView.getUint8(offset), dataView.getUint8(offset + 1), dataView.getUint8(offset + 2), dataView.getUint8(offset + 3));
      const frameSize = dataView.getUint32(offset + 4, false);
      const flags = dataView.getUint16(offset + 8, false);

      const anyFramIdExtractor = this.extractTextFrame(dataView, offset + 10, frameSize);

   
  
      if (frameID === 'TALB') {
        const albumName = this.extractTextFrame(dataView, offset + 10, frameSize);
     
        
      } 
    
      else if(frameID==='APIC'){
       

        const imgString=this.extractTextFrame(dataView, offset + 10, frameSize);
        console.log(imgString) //<<-- here i am getting binary of the image but getting error in     //in opening url .
        var base64EncodedStr = Buffer.from(decodeURI(encodeURIComponent(imgString))).toString('base64');
var src = "data:image/png;base64," + base64EncodedStr ;
//but still the result turns out to be corrupted 
        
      }
  
      offset += frameSize + 10; // Add 10 bytes for the frame header
    }
  }
```

i try with passing the imgString like  below .

may be the format of asking question appears to be in  poorly managed  or spelling mistakes  but i will we happy to welcome any suggestions or edits . i removed unnecessary code part which is unrelated to the  current focused problem .

Comment: There are **so many** ways to add album art to an MP3.  There are several ID3 versions that put their data in different places, some at the beginning, some at the end.  I don't know your motivation for not wanting to use a third party library, but I recommend reconsidering.